# how to go about tensorflow installation for ubuntu 32bit system

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, ubuntu, tensorflow

Is there any way to install tensorflow for the ubuntu32 bit system.
Iam using python 2.7
Any suggestions how to go about the installation process

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux

Comment: What have you already tried?